# UISearchController or another option for a service request result?

Tags: swift, web-services, search, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I've been reading some examples of the use of `UISearchController` that looks fine for searching and filtering results when you have a local data source. I instead would like the user to provide a string and to request a list of results to a service, then display the results in a table view.

Would it be `UISearchController` and a search bar suitable for this scenario? Or maybe just a simple text field? How would the most appropriate way to get the user input for his search be for a search by means of a service call?

I would appreciate some tutorial with similar purpose.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the experience of creating an application that with help of http requests searches for data on the server and displays the results to the user. I recommend for the basics to use UIViewController with UISearchBar (+ UISearchBarDelegate) and UITableView (+ UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource).

Sample view:

[image]

That app had difficult animations and view design. Because of that I can't use UISearchBarController. But, I you want to make search like apple recommended, use UISearchBarController.